# Office.js item saveAsync doesn't save all fields on new appointment

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I am using Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync in an Outlook add-in to save a new appointment. The returned item id is used to fetch the appointment using the REST api (a get request to Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + '/v2.0/me/events/' + itemId). This returns an appointment where Start, End, and Organizer is set correctly, but the Subject, Body, Location, Recurrence, Attendees is not set.

Does saveAsync not save all fields on the appointment?

I am using the REST api because the Recurrence field is not available through the Office.context.mailbox.item in older versions of the Outlook JavaScript API.

Comment: What client are you on? Outlook Web Access or Outlook Windows Desktop, or Mac Outlook etc. If on Windows Desktop, and in Cached Mode, it is likely those properties haven't sync'ed up to the server yet. The Recurrence Field was added to help avoid these sync issues, so that should be used when possible.

Comment: I am using Outlook Web Access

Comment: Are you connecting to an Office365 account?

Comment: Yes I am connecting to an Office 356 account

Comment: Is this in the [Outlook Web beta](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-help-with-the-new-outlook-on-the-web-017014cd-2ad0-41ab-8473-6bd8c349d4f8) or in the old client?

Comment: It is the old client. Actually I don't see the option to enable the new client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario occurs when calling Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync on a new Calendar item that has not been sent yet. This has been fixed in the new Outlook Web beta. The API should behave as designed in Mail and on Existing Calendar items. Note that for existing Calendar items, an update may be sent out to attendees depending on the changes that the user or the add-in made in the compose form.